# Is there anyway to wrap-content height for top and match-parent for bottom?

Tags: android, xml

I was always curious about height and width can be wrap for one direction and match for the other direction

lets suppose

here is a linear layout

```
<LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>
```

Is it possible that we can implement wrap-content for height for the top and for bottom it will be macth-parent

here is a imaginary scenario

```
<LinearLayout
    
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content|top"
            android:layout_height="match_parent|bottom"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vasant

```
android:layout_width : means view of a width
android:layout_height: means view of a height

top / bottom : means of gravity of a view 

If you want to move the view then you use the x and y property
```